# Regex cut string until a special characters

Tags: regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

i have a code like `onclick=window.location='abc.html'> lala` , i want to make a regular expression to cut this to meet the following requirments:

1. if there is a `>` then the result should be `> lala`
2. if there is not `>` then the string will cut till the space and the result will only be `lala`

i have done the following the preg_replace, but i am wrong, what is the problem?

```
$text=preg_replace('/(onclick)(.*?)(>|\s)/','',$text);
```

Comment: in other words, you are trying to remove all onclick attributes from an html page?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/(onclick)(.*?)((?=>)|\s)/','',"onclick=window.location='abc.html'> lala");
echo preg_replace('/(onclick)(.*?)((?=>)|\s)/','',"onclick=window.location='abc.html' lala");
?>
```

You have to make the search for the > a look ahead so it doesn't get captured and replaced. (?=>)

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = preg_replace('/onclick.+?((\s|>).+)/', "$1", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do that is to use the DOM, example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHtml($yourHtmlDocument);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$tags = $xpath->query("//*[@onclick]");
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tag->removeAttribute('onclick');
}
$result = $doc->saveHtml();
```